# I want to automate downloading CSV files from a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, scripting, export-to-csv

This is the link for the Website.

https://data.gov.in/catalog/district-wise-and-month-wise-queries-farmers-kisan-call-centre-kcc-during-2020?filters%5Bfield_catalog_reference%5D=6752810&format=json&offset=0&limit=6&sort%5Bcreated%5D=desc

There are multiple files per page and for each file there is an 'Export CSV' Button. It also asks you to fill out a form before you can download the files each time. I'd prefer to use node js since i have some experience in Js but I have not done any projects in Nodejs. What approach can I use?

Edit: I'd also appreciate any links to any articles which are on similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Puppeteer https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer.
See one example here :  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-scheduled-news-crawler-with-puppeteer-d02a7919bdbe
Search for "web scraping", "web scraping with Puppeteer" on Google